# Copy data from content editable div to hidden input for form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to properly copy my data from my contenteditable div so that i can submit it to my database. this will be for a post similar to Facebook. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="urlinput" class="isPlaceholder" role="textbox" spellcheck="true"   aria-multiline="true"  data-placeholder-default="This is the Status text" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

and after some data is typed in, the html looks like this:

```
<div id="urlinput" class="isPlaceholder" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" aria-multiline="true" data-placeholder-default="This is the Status text" contenteditable="true">This is line one<div>This is line two</div><div>This is line 3</div><div><br></div></div>
```

Since with contenteditable divs every line is separated with another div, whats the best way to go about doing this safely and still keeping the structure so when I pull the data later from my database it still stays formatted the same way when i put it in the view.

Comment: so let me see if I understood. You want to be able have the div urlinput inside a form and on submit, you want to send that to the database. Correct?

Comment: Put the innerHTML of #urlinput into a hidden form field and post it.  That will contain, as text, all the inner <div>s which is what I think you want.

Comment: OP, be very aware of [XSS attacks](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/) if you want to allow users to store html in your database especially since the point seems to be to show that html to others on your site

Comment: I don't want to allow users to store html, but i do need to save the data to my database then retrieve it with it having the same text structure, in other words line one, line 2, ext. Could i just encode it when storing , then decode it when posting. if so whats the most secure and clean way. and is that the same as escaping special characters. will i loose the characters? Thanks any feed back is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`var contentEditableContent = $('#urlinput').html();`

Your content editable div looks familiar, is that Medium Editor? If so, you can grab the content via its API by doing:

`editor.serialize()['element-0'].value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the content of editable div before sending to server and decode after retrieving back from server.

Encode :

```
var urlinputVal = $("#urlinput").html();
var toSend = $('<span/>').text(urlinputVal).html();
```

Decode :

```
var toRender = $('<span/>').text(serverVal).text();
$("#urlinput").html(toRender);
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question, I'm confused on the <span/> part of the answer, can you explain please.

Comment: It creates in memory container for the value to put it and retrieve back. It can be any tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was this answer worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329143/5988187

It was a little while ago...
I simplified it

```
  <script>
    function GetDivToHidden() {
      var divVal = document.getElementById('EditDiv').innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('EditDivHidden').value = divVal;
    }
  </script>

html ...
 <asp:HiddenField ID="EditDivHidden" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"></asp:HiddenField>
<div class="div-edit" id="EditDiv" contenteditable="true" ></div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return GetDivToHidden();" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```